# Pandas - mapping values between DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df_players`:

```
   rank  player_id        posicao
0    39      82730        Goleiro
1   136     100651       Atacante
2   140      87863  Meio-Campista
3    66      83257       Atacante
4   139     101290       Atacante
```

---

`df_players.info()`:

```
Data columns (total 3 columns):
rank         733 non-null int64
player_id    733 non-null int64
posicao      733 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
```

---

And I have this `df_games`:

```
   jogo_id  rodada_id  time_id     time_nome  adversario_id adversario_nome  ...  preco_num  variacao_num  media_num  jogos_num status   ano
0   232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267           Vasco  ...       2.00          0.00        0.0          0   Nulo  2019
1   232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267           Vasco  ...       4.00          0.00        0.0          0   Nulo  2019
2   232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267           Vasco  ...       2.00          0.00        0.0          0   Nulo  2019
3   232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267           Vasco  ...       2.00          0.00        0.0          0   Nulo  2019
4   232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267           Vasco  ...       5.83         -2.17        0.4          1   Nulo  2019
```

---

`df_games.info()`:

```
Data columns (total 19 columns):
...
player_id          30042 non-null int64
...
dtypes: float64(7), int64(7), object(5)
```

---

Now I'm trying to pass `rank` values from `df_players` to `df_games` using 'player_id', present on both dfs, like so:

```
df_games['rank'] = df_games['atleta_id'].map(df_players['rank'])
```

But ranks are all printing `NaN` after the operation.

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there, just add `set_index()` inside the `map`

```
df_games['rank'] = df_games['atleta_id'].map(df_players.set_index('player_id')['rank'])
```

A more readable way

```
s = df_players.set_index('player_id')['rank']
df_games['rank'] = df_games['atleta_id'].map(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pd.merge to bring rank from df_games.

```
df_games.merge(df_players[['rank','player_id']],on='player_id',how='left')
```

You can also see more details from documentation of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).